# Recursively create all given tree paths in a list?

Tags: c#, winforms, recursion, treeview

I have some strings that look:

```
/Test Town
/Test Town/Interior
/Test Dungeon/Secret
```

Given an arbitrary list of pathes, how can I generate the leaf nodes automatically? I imagine the solution involves recursion but I can't quite get it.

I tried to do it using a loop but I only got the first level.

The above would produce something like:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to filter the list to return only leaf nodes? Or do you want a tree structure as a result?

Comment: @Enigmativity I just want the tree structure - so a root nodes and then the children all separated. I'll edit my post with a picture if it's not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works fairly well.

First, I had to create a tree structure:

```
public class Tree<T> : List<Tree<T>>
{
    public Tree(T value, IEnumerable<Tree<T>> children)
    {
        this.Value = value;
        this.AddRange(children);
    }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now I needed a recursive function to build the tree up:

```
Func<
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>,
    IEnumerable<Tree<string>>>
        buildTree = null;

buildTree = xss =>
    xss
        .ToLookup(xs => xs.FirstOrDefault(), xs => xs.Skip(1))
        .Where(xs => xs.Key != null)
        .Select(xs => new Tree<string>(xs.Key, buildTree(xs)));
```

Then, given I have a list of strings in a `lines` variable, I just needed to execute:

```
var tree =
    buildTree(lines
        .Select(x => new [] { "Root", }.Concat(x.Split('/').Skip(1))));
```

And that's it. If you don't count the `Tree<T>` class, then this is just three lines of code. Simple.

---

As alternative, if you don't want to use an anonymous method, you could modify the tree class like so:

```
public class Tree<T> : List<Tree<T>>
{
    public Tree(T value, IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> inner)
    {
        this.Value = value;
        this.AddRange(inner
            .ToLookup(xs => xs.FirstOrDefault(), xs => xs.Skip(1))
            .Where(xs => xs.Key != null)
            .Select(xs => new Tree<T>(xs.Key, xs)));
    }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now it would be called like this:

```
var tree = new Tree<string>("Root", lines.Select(x => x.Split('/').Skip(1)));
```

However, this means that you need to be in control of the `Tree<T>` class.

The first solution means you can use any tree structure.

---

Here's a version that works for `System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode`:

```
Func<
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>,
    IEnumerable<TreeNode>>
        buildTreeNode = null;
buildTreeNode = xss =>
    xss
        .ToLookup(xs => xs.FirstOrDefault(), xs => xs.Skip(1))
        .Where(xs => xs.Key != null)
        .Select(xs => new TreeNode(xs.Key, buildTreeNode(xs).ToArray()));
```

Comment: I guess I would then have to a do in-order traversal of this tree and create Tree-Nodes out of them?

Comment: @VaughanHilts - No, just replace my `Tree<T>` class with the one you're working with. You might have to do some wriggling of the code, but you should be able to do it fairly easily.

Comment: Where is that StartWith method defined?

Comment: Going to give this a shot now, then. Hopefully I can wrap it around my head. :)

Comment: @fcuesta - Sorry, `StartWith` is an Interactive Extensions from the Reactive Framework team. I'll replace it with a `Concat`.

Comment: The TreeNode class doesn't really take a generic parameter... excuse my ignorance. I'm only a novice to potentially intermediate at C#. All the insane LINQ is making my head boggle. :) How would I generate a tree of this class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.aspx

Comment: @VaughanHilts - I'm glad you got it. I thought I'd add my version too that works with `System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode`.